# what is this query outputting?

Tags: mysql, datetime

So,
I want to run a quick query to give me some information on times taken to send messages.

my plan is

1. count how many messages we are sending
2. work out the difference between the max and the min datetime for the messages
3. work out how much time it took per message.

So my query ended up being

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id)                                                          AS message_sent,
TIMEDIFF(MAX(msg_sent_datetime), MIN(msg_sent_datetime))           AS total_time_taken,
COUNT(id)/TIMEDIFF(MAX(msg_sent_datetime), MIN(msg_sent_datetime)) AS time_per_message
FROM sent_txts_none_action_child 
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

The first two sections work fine.
You run into trouble with number three.

Example output.

```
message_sent|total_time_taken|time_per_message
5           |00:00:01        |5.0000000000
5           |00:00:00        |NULL
5           |00:00:01        |5.0000000000
7647        |00:28:12        |2.7194167852
```

What is the third column outputting?
What do I need to change to get it to output the correct value?

---

#### Edit

ok so after making the suggested change in the comment I get

```
message_sent|total_time_taken|time_per_message
5           |00:00:01        |0.2000000000
5           |00:00:00        |0.0000000000
5           |00:00:01        |0.2000000000
7647        |00:28:12        |0.3677259056
```

which still is not what we want.
as if you times `0.3677259056` by `7647` you get `2812`.

So whats the issue?
MYSQL is not converting the datediff value to anything logical,

instead it is treating it as a simple number and ignoring any non numeric characters...

Why does mysql not convert this to seconds/milliseconds?

Is there a function I can use to do this?

Comment: Isn't time per message going to be TIMEDIFF(stuff)/COUNT(*) ?  Aren't your NULLs due to divide checks?

Comment: What is the definition of msg_sent_datetime?  Are messages sent one at a time, or are multiple messages sent at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

TIMEDIFF() returns a time value.  However, when you perform any numeric maths on it, it turns into a numeric value that is useless (just mashing the digits from the time in textual form).

> work out how much time it took per message.

So you really mean, `time / message-count`.  The divisor should be the count.

What you got is the inverse, which is messages that could be sent *per unit time*, which is *seconds*.  In other words, what you calculated is how many messages could be sent per second, on average.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id)                                                          AS message_sent,
TIMEDIFF(MAX(msg_sent_datetime), MIN(msg_sent_datetime))           AS total_time_taken,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(msg_sent_datetime), MIN(msg_sent_datetime)))/COUNT(id) AS time_per_message
FROM sent_txts_none_action_child 
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

The resultant `time_per_message` column is measured in seconds.

Reference: [TIME_TO_SEC()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

Comment: Also, as a matter of curiosity, When would my initial calculation be useful?

Comment: @Hailwood / See updated answer. Your initial calc, the inverse form, could be useful to find out the maximum capacity in terms of messages per unit time.

Comment: Thank you :) I was hoping there was a function similar to TIME_TO_SEC :)